# How to force JSON to use primitive type boolean

Tags: json, pojo

Is there a trick to get a JSON POST message to be forced to a boolean primitive type? I have two data/value pairs:

```
"isDeveloper": true, // Boolean Object type
"isMale": true, // force to primitive type boolean
```

Comment: Could you add some more information, and what you want to do that you can't accomplish with the Boolean Object type?

Comment: JSON itself doesn't use anything but primitive type boolean. Maybe your question title should talk about getting pojo to do this.

Comment: Is there a way to get Postman to do this? That's what I'm using to send the JSON message

Answer (score 0):

if you use python, transform the json post in a map:

```
import json
result = json.loads(json_file)
```